# How do I press Ctrl+Alt+Delete in VirtualBox?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, ctrl-alt-delete

I'm running VirtualBox with Windows Vista as host OS and Windows Server 2008 as guest OS. To login to Windows Server I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, but my host OS reacts on that so I can not send it to VirtualBox. How can I do it?

Comment: on a mac host OS, with xp as the guest OS, how do you do control alt delete to log in?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Usually there is an entry in a menu somewhere. <kbd>Host key</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd><sup>1</sup> should work too, though.

If you're using Remote Desktop, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> instead.

---

<sup>1</sup> You should know what your host key is, but it's configurable. Mine usually was Right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

If you want to know what your Host Key is, open VirtualBox and go to *File → Preferences → Input*. If you don't like the current key, you can change it to whatever you wish.

Comment: Just curious, how did you get the keystrokes in the answer to look like keys? I looked in the markdown documentation and couldn't see any way to do it...

Comment: @nhinkle: Stack Overflow's (and Super User's) style sheet abuses the `<kbd>` tag for that purpose. It's not part of Markdown.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I've never seen that used before. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Corporate Geek, please use proper arrows when editing my posts. `->` is an ugly abomination I don't want to have associated with my name.

Comment: @nhinkle, Just press `edit` to get the source. `edited` → `source` also works.

Comment: @Joey, What does a "host key" mean anyway? What's the equivalent of that in VMware?

Comment: @Pacerier: The host key is the modifier that is used for shortcuts in the VM software itself and are not passed to the VM inside. And I have no idea.

Comment: @Pacerier wow, and award for "digging up a comment from 5 years ago for something I no doubt know now" goes to.... you!

Comment: @Pacerier I had 826 reputation points on May 13th, 2010, and at that time suggested edits weren't a thing, so there would not have been any edit button available. Back then the only way to view source was to know the URL to see the source view, there was no button for it exposed in the UI.

Comment: @nhinkle, Ic.͏͏

Comment: @Joey, What if we wanted to pass the "host key" into the VM?

Comment: @Pacerier: You cannot. That's why it's usually bound to a key you have a spare of, e.g. Right Ctrl or Right Shift.

Comment: @Joey, But when you host a VM inside a VM, you'll need a way to pass the "host key" into the VM. There got to be a way to do it even without unlimited keys.

Comment: @Pacerier: Don't do that to a level where you run out of keys, then. Seriously, what's the point of this discussion?

Comment: @Joey, To figure out how to send a host key into a VM within a VM. That's definitely useful.  I'm currently remote-desktoped on a server through a client which is itself host to a remote-desktop session of which the client is *this* physical laptop.

Comment: like a charm! !!

Answer (score 19):

On an OS X host, try

- <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>alt/option</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> or
- <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>

I used the onscreen keyboard in Windows 7 which showed the guest OS receiving `ctrl` and `alt/option`, but not `delete`. By adding the `fn` key to the combination, it seems the Mac's idea of "delete" (normally like Windows' "backspace") becomes Windows' "delete".

Comment: There is no delete button on 13" MacBooks :(

Comment: cmd + fn + delete did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

In the menu called `Input`, click `Keyboard` then `Insert Ctrl+Alt+Del`:

[image: virtualbox ctrl-alt-del]

A reminder of the shortcut is also visible there.

Note: In older versions it used to be in the `Machine` menu.

Comment: What if you are in fullscreen....

Comment: @Pacerier: If you are in fullscreen, then the solutions of Joey and Christian are more convenient, you just have to remember the keys combination.

Comment: In more recent versions of Virtualbox, this option is found in the "Input" menu rather than the "Machine" menu