# How to send Alt+Ctrl+Del key sequence in a VirtualBox VM guest

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ctrl-alt-delete

I have a [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) VM guest, which I run in vboxHeadless mode.
The host is Linux 64-bit. The VirtualBox version is 4.2.12r84980.

The VM loads fine, and I am presented with the "windows server" greeting screen. That is, I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> to log on.

I have tried numerous ways to send <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>:

- Remote desktop to the VM from the port that is assigned by VirtualBox headless. That is, <VirtualBox host IP address>: VMguestPort. A-C-D doesn't work as the key sequence gets intercepted by the client PC at which I'm sitting and trying to log on to the VM guest.
- Remote desktop directly to the VM <Windows Server 2008 VM guest IP address>:3389 doesn't work for the same reason.
- [phpVirtualBox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpvirtualbox/) gives an a button to send A-C-D to a VM guest. This doesn't work either.
- I read that from a command line I could use the command

  ```
  VBoxManage controlvm win2k8_64 keyboardputscancode 1d 38 53

  VBoxManage controlvm win2k8_64 keyboardputscancode 9D B8 D3
  ```

for key press and then key release sequence. This doesn't work either.

Why do these work? Especially with a Windows Server 2008 as a VM guest?

---

The suggested previous answer does not work (pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> does not work either) and also, as I am running a headless server, there isn't any change for me to see the VirtualBox GUI. The best I can get is the phpVirtualBox web interface and in VirtualBox there isn't any "right Ctrl" capture key.

Comment: This has been answered [here](http://superuser.com/questions/116946/how-do-i-press-ctrlaltdelete-in-virtualbox).

Answer (score 8):

The default method is the <kbd>Host</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> sequence in VirtualBox. The default host key binding is generally the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

[image: ctl-alt-del]

Additionally, you check/change your <kbd>Host</kbd> key binding within the *Input* section under *File → Preferences* in your VirtualBox Manager.

[image]