# Ctrl+Alt+Del not working with or without host button

Tags: virtual-machine, login, ctrl-alt-delete

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> doesn't work in my oracle VM including using the host key.

the keys just dont work the way they should, yet they seem to work individually?

Any ideas on what can fix this problem, as it's extremely annoying?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I press Ctrl+Alt+Delete in VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/116946/how-do-i-press-ctrlaltdelete-in-virtualbox)